# Azure Rate Card meter rates without the offer discount

Tags: azure, rate, discount

I know how to programmatically get the rate card for azure . but the rates come with discount . Is there a way to get the rate card without the discount.
( i need another way than the obvious : add the discount to the rate ) . 
In Other words i need the prices/rates as seen in the azure calculator.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `but the rates come with discount`? From what I understand, the rate card is fetched for a plan (MS-AZR-XXXXP) and the plan includes discounts.

Comment: yeah that's right , in the json is named Offer , and it has discount. "OfferTerms": [
    {
      "Name": "Overage discount",


      "Discount": 0.15,
      "EffectiveDate": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },


what i need to know is the actual rate/price before that discount

Comment: You have to do that calculation manually using the discount value. You have all the data to do it just not done automatically.